# Visual editor for imputing sqlite foreign key ids using another field

Tags: sqlite, tools

Here's my use case: I want to build a simple database that maps a reverse DNS domain back to an email sending service, and information about that service. I have a table of email source information and a table of reverse DNS base domains. Both tables use integers for IDs, because services could rebrand/rename at any time, but they generally keep the reverse DNS domain the unchanged. A sending email service might use multiple reverse DNS domains (Looking at you, MailChimp).

I've built out the data in the `senders` table using public information and a little Python but tying the reverse DNS to the service will take some manual work. It'd like to be able to use a GUI that would allow me to use autocomplete to fill in the `name` field from the `sender` table, to populate the `sender_id` field in the `reverse_dns` table, so I can link the two records together without needing to lookup the `sender` `id` every time I add a new reverse DNS entry. So far, I've tried DataGrip, DB Browser for SQLite, and the SQLite3 Editor extension for Visual Studio Code, but I haven't been able to get these tools to do what I want.

I guess I could build a little Flask app for this, but there's probably a better existing solution. Any suggestions?

The table schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "senders" (
    "id" INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "spf_aligned" INTEGER,
    "dkim_aligned" INTEGER,
    "known_to_forward" INTEGER,
    "forward_dkim_intact" INTEGER,
    "forward_own_envelope_domain" INTEGER,
    "support_url" TEXT,
    "dmarc_io_uri" TEXT UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT),
    CHECK("spf_aligned" = 0 or "spf_aligned" = 1),
    CHECK("dkim_aligned" = 0 or "dkim_aligned" = 1),
    CHECK("known_to_forward" = 0 or "known_to_forward" = 1),
    CHECK("forward_dkim_intact" = 0 or "forward_dkim_intact" = 1),
    CHECK(
    "forward_own_envelope_domain" = 0 or "forward_own_envelope_domain" = 1
    )
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "reverse_dns" (
    "id" INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "base_domain" TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "sender_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT),
    FOREIGN KEY(sender_id) REFERENCES senders(id)
)
```